# Setting $this->something in class body, can't use constructor dependency injection

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I have a Symfony controller that uses a data_provider service. I can't figure out how to initialise this service.

I tried:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller {
    public $dataProvider=$this->get('data_provider');
```

That causes an error, can't use constructor in a Controller so that leaves me with:

```
public $dataProvider=false;
public function someAction(){
  $this->dataProvider=$this->get('data_provider');
...
public function anotherAction(){
  $this->dataProvider=$this->get('data_provider');
...
```

So I have to set it every time in the controller action function. Is there an easy way to initialise the dataProvider when the controller is created?

The service is only for this bundle so it's defined in Symfony/src/mmt/myBundle/Resources/config/services.yml and that file is loaded by Symfony/src/mmt/myBundle/DependencyInjection/myExtension.php. Not sure if that makes a difference but I would prefer something that doesn't need changes to  files outside the bundle.

Using symfony 2.3.4

**[update]**

After a seemingly endless list of instructions that cover less than half of what you need to do to get it working I got the injection part to work. Thanks to everyone giving me excellent advice.

1. My service is part of my bundle and don't want to change config files outside the bundle to load it. To make sure that Symfony/src/mmt/mrBundle/Resources/config/services.yml gets loaded you need a file called Symfony/src/mmt/mrBundle/DependencyInjection/mmtmrExtension.php (no, don't use just any name for the php file it's related to your application and bundle name).

What is in that file is explained [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html). I didn't need to do anything there because it was created when I created the bundle and have it create most of the files. (creating a bundle is in the standard documentation)

2.

Added a data_provider service in the services.yml file: (read standard documentation about setting up your db with doctrine)

```
data_provider:
    class: mmt\mrBundle\Services\dataProvider
    arguments: [ @doctrine.orm.entity_manager ]
```

Content of: Symfony/src/mmt/mrBundle/Services/dataProvider.php

```
<?php
namespace mmt\mrBundle\Services;
class dataProvider 
{
    protected $em;
    public function __construct($em){
        $this->em = $em;
    }
    public function getItem($id){
        $item = $this->em->getRepository('mmtmrBundle:Item')
            ->find($id);
        return $item;
    }
    public function saveItem($item){
        $this->em->persist($item);
        $this->em->flush();
    }
}
?>
```

Now that I have the service I can use it in the controller like so:

```
$this->get("data_provider")->getItem(22);
```

But I would like my DefaultController have a $this->dataProvider when DefaultController is created. Preferably one depending on dev, prod, and test.

In comes dependency injection. Add the following to Symfony/src/mmt/mrBundle/Resources/config/services.yml

```
mmt.mr.DefaultController:
     class: mmt\mrBundle\Controller\DefaultController
     arguments: [@data_provider]
     calls: 
         - [ "setContainer", [ @service_container ] ]
```

Now use the mmt.mr.DefaultController:indexAction (don't use mmtmrBundle:Default:index) in your routes:

/var/www/html/Symfony/src/mmt/mrBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml

```
mmtmr_homepage:
    path:  /{id}
    requirements:
      id: \d+
    defaults: { _controller: mmt.mr.DefaultController:indexAction, id: false }
```

In Symfony/src/mmt/mrBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php should look like this:

```
<?php
namespace mmt\mrBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
class DefaultController extends Controller {
    public $dataProvider;
    public function __construct($data_provider){
        $this->dataProvider = $data_provider;
    }
    public function indexAction($id) {
        $item=$this->dataProvider->getItem($id);
        return $this->render('mmtmrBundle:Default:index.html.twig', 
                array('item' => $item));
    }
}
?>
```

I think that's it, of something is missing please let me know. Congrats; you now know how to inject dependency (If you didn't already). The bad news is that by the time you read this it's probably out of date and you have to go to the Symfony site. Documentation is good there but didn't mention any of the things that broke it for me.

Comment: Are you sure you defined your `routing.yml` as `{ _controller: m.y.DefaultController:indexAction }` and cleared the cache ?

Comment: @touki Changed the router and now the method is called (opted for calls in the services.yml). Because that gave me an error I added the __construct function but get the same error: `Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /var/www/html/Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php line 252`

Comment: Yes, You need to add `calls: [ "setContainer", [ @service_container ] ]` into your service declaration in order to inject the service container to the controller.

Comment: @Touki Opted for the contructor again according to the documentation but it looks like in the action functions and constructor $this refers to something other than DefaultController. Trying to set $DataSource in the constructor: `$this->$dataProvider = $data_provider;` results in `Cannot access empty property` Leaving it empty is useless because the point of this whole exercise it to set the $this->dataProvider

Comment: @Touki Sorry, forget about it `$this->$dataProvider` isn't valid PHP to access a property.

Comment: @Touki Thank you, the added calls was needed. Funny that the documentation never mentions this: symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html

Comment: @HMR read also http://mnapoli.fr/controllers-as-services/ to see alternative solution. I won't create an answer since you are specifically asking about Symfony, but maybe you would be interested to know about alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should inject it in the controller using Depency Injection.

Based on the classes in your question you can do the following:

Symfony/src/mmt/mrBundle/Resources/config/services.yml

```
   mmt.mr.DefaultController:
         class: mmt\mrBundle\Controller\DefaultController
         calls: 
             - [ setContainer, [ @service_container ] ]
             - [ setDataProvider, [ @data_provider ] ]
```

Symfony/src/mmt/mrBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php

```
public function setDataProvider($provider){
    if($this->dataProvider===false){
        $this->dataProvider=$provider;
    }
}
```

Make sure you use the service name and then the action in your router, for example:

Symfony/src/mmt/mrBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml

```
mmtmr_homepage:
    path:  /{id}
    requirements:
      id: \d+
    defaults: { _controller: mmt.mr.DefaultController:indexAction, id: false }
```

`mmt.mr.DefaultController` is the name used in your services.yml and `:indexAction` is the function called indexAction in your DefaultController.php

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I created a solution based on creating an event listener and calling a method on kernel.controller but I like this one better. What would the values for setDataProvider and `@mydataprovider` be? I think it may be setDataProvider is a public function in DefaultController that sets $this->dataProvider. Then `@mydataprovider` would be the classname of the dataprovider and symfony will create a new one? So if it's `m\yBundle\DB\dbProvider.php` then `@mydataprovider` would be `@m.yBundle.DB.dbProvider`?

Comment: Not really. When call $this->get, you are actually asking for a service/object from your container. You are giving it the key of the item, you want to fetch. So you will have to replace the @mydataprovider with the key : `@data_provider`. You might want to read the chapter on dependeny injection on Symfony : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

Comment: That seems to be a correct way. Might worth reading - [How to define a Controller as service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html)

Comment: Hi Michiel, I've updated my question. I'm not getting any errors but nothing is happening when I call the indexAction of the DefaultController by requesting the index page. I was expecting the setDataProvider method of DefaultController to be called with a new instance of my dataProvider class.

Comment: @Touki Thank you for the link, too bad it generates an error, I've updated my question with the result.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use a method that returns the service.

Something like:

```
public function getDataProvider()
{
    return $this->get('data_provider');
}
```

And create a 'AdvancedController' that extends the Symfony2 Controller, put this method in it, and let all your controllers extend it.

In the AdvancedController you can put all your global methods that you use in controllers, it's really comfortable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, would that call `getDataProvider()` every time I use `$this->dataProvider`? Or do I have to call $this->getDataprovider() every time I need it? I'm leaning towards the yml injection especially if I can set different values for prod, dev and test.

Comment: Every time you need it you can call the method, like: `$dataProvider = $this->getDataProvidet()`
Or `$data = $this->getDataProvider()->getData();`

Comment: This method is not the best. In your case you should use dependency injections. In the next post it is described how to inject it. 
You have to inject it and get the class in the controllers constructor.

Comment: Thank you Edmund, I am trying to go for the injection. Got the data_provider service to work but can't get it injected into the DefaultController service.

Answer (score 0):

After use the depedency injection, $data_provider must be correctly given to your controller so why do you not use it in:

```
public function dataInit($data_provider){
  $logger = $this->get('logger');
  $logger->notice('from dataInit so this works');
}
```

maybe it's must be:

```
public function dataInit($data_provider){
  $logger = $data_provider->getLogger();
  $logger->notice('from dataInit so this works');
}
```

If no, please paste you dataProvider class

Comment: I've updated the question, hope not everything is as hard as this was. The link http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html got me there most of the way but somehow a controller isn't a controller any more after you make it a service and the contructor is never called if you don't use the service name for it in your router (both not mentioned in the article). For the controller not being a controller I had to add ` [ "setContainer", [ @service_container ] ]` to my services.yml and for the contructor not being called I had to change the routing.yml. Big thanks to taoki